# Titlesec with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I still confuse myself with `titlesec` and `tikz`. For example, in the below code, how do I place the chapter number and the title inside a rounded rectangle with a custom inner margin?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=36pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [hang]% shape
  {\centering\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {\thechapter}% label
  {10pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter Title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that the final part in the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` is passed the title as an argument.

Borrowing the code from matexmatics

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=36pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  [block]% shape
  {\filcenter\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{\thechapter}}% before the title body
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  [block]% shape
  {\filcenter\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{\ignorespaces}}% before the title body

\newcommand{\maketitleframe}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rounded corners] {#1 #2};
  \end{tikzpicture}% before the title body
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's important to define a format also for numberless chapters. With `\ignorespaces` as the first argument, the space between `#1` and `#2` is swallowed. Note

1. `\filcenter` and not `\centering`
2. 0pt and not 10pt

If you want more space between the number and the title

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=36pc, margin=5pc,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  [block]% shape
  {\filcenter\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{\thechapter\hspace{10pt}}}% before the title body
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}
  [block]% shape
  {\filcenter\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\maketitleframe{}}% before the title body

\newcommand{\maketitleframe}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,rounded corners] {#1#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}% before the title body
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Am I seeing it wrong? I included `showframe` option in the `geometry` and it "looks" as if the rectangle is not centered, and it leans a bit more close to right.

Comment: @blackened I fixed `block` instead of `hang` and the spacings to 0pt.

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to use the option `explicit` for the package `titlesec`. Then the title can be obtained with `#1`. The command `\thechapter` is moved to the `\node` where `#1` is placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=36pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
  [hang]% shape
  {\centering\bfseries\large}% format applied to label+text
  {}% label
  {10pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {\begin{tikzpicture}\node[draw,rounded corners] {\thechapter{} #1};\end{tikzpicture}}% before the title body
  []% after the title body

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\tableofcontents`…

Comment: @egreg This answer was only meant to show that the option `explicit` allows to use `#1` and how a `tikzpicture` can be used for the title. It was not intended as a full code: for example the `10pt` is out of place and it does not consider numberless chapters. Your answer is definitely more sophisticated.